# TypeError: cyclic object value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
sendMail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // fetch('/https://uczsieapp-mailer.herokuapp.com/', {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var contactReason = document.getElementById('contactReason');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var additionalInfo = document.getElementById('additionalInfo');
    var body = JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
            contactReason: contactReason,
            email: email,
            additionalInfo: additionalInfo,
        }
    );
    console.log(body);
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name,
                contactReason: contactReason,
                email: email,
                additionalInfo: additionalInfo,
            }
        )
    });
}
```

The code references this HTML:

```
<form>
    <input className="form_input input_margin" type="text" id='name' name="name"
           placeholder="Imię"/>
    <input className="form_input_2" type="text" name="email" id='email'
           placeholder="Adres e-mail"/>
    <textarea name='additionalInfo' id='additionalInfo' className="form_textarea"
              type="text" placeholder="Dodatkowe informacje"/>
    <button onClick={this.sendMail} className="btn button_send">Wyślij</button>
</form>
```

So what I understand it's referencing something, that's being changed, but how does anyone know where exactly this error is and why?

I get this error on the `JSON.stringify()` method. Creating an object without `stringify()` works.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value

Comment: Yes, I read it. I still don't understand why that's throwing an error

Comment: The same article has a code snippet to check and filter cyclic reference. You should use that figure out which property is throwing this error.

Comment: What do you want to do in your code? Why are you stringifying directly dom object? Shouldn't you get the innerHTML of those instead ?

Comment: @Axnyff You were right. I completely missed that. Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem comes with the fact that you are directly trying to stringify DOM elements ( which probably contain circular references).

What you should do, is probably something like that:

```
 var body = JSON.stringify({
        name: name.value,
        contactReason: contactReason.value,
        email: email.value,
        additionalInfo: additionalInfo.value,
    }
 );
```

If you want to post the values of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error using React.  For some reason I had two instances of the "React Context DevTool".  I also reset the other react devtools in my addins by disabling, then re-enabling them.  The error went away.  - E