# TypeError Cyclic Object Value in Angular 6 when using POST-Method

Tags: json, angular, http, post

I am getting an TypeError: Cyclic Object Value when creating an object from input values and sending a POST request to my BackEnd. I guess it's a problem when converting into JSON.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fehler/Cyclic_object_value

Referring to this issue it could be caused by binding input values to components variable with [(ngModel)], but I couldn't solve this issue yet with the given solution.
[TypeError: cyclic object value in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965551/typeerror-cyclic-object-value-in-react?answertab=active#tab-top)

Below my code:
component.html:

```
<tr>
  <td>Key: </td>
  <td><input [(ngModel)]="key" placeholder="Key"/></td>
</tr>
<!--... getting more values with input using [(ngModel)] like above -->
```

component.ts:

```
key: string;
// ... more variables
```

object.service.ts:

```
createLeafSetting(key: string, ...) {
  // creates object from input parameters
  const s: Setting = {
    keyName: key,
    // ... multiple parameters
  };

  // this adds object to observable array
  this.addSettingToObservableArray(s);
  // this calls the POST method in apiservice with observable array as parameter
  this.apiService.createOrUpdateSettings(this.settings$).subscribe();
}
```

api.service.ts:

```
/** Sends changed or newly created objects to API*/
createOrUpdateSettings(setting: Observable<Setting[]>) {
  return this.httpClient.post<Setting[]>(this.API_URL + '/settings', setting)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('createOrUpdateSettings', []))
    );
}
```

Can anyone suggests a solid solution for this or a workaround to find the specific part in code which causes the TypeError: Cyclic Object Value?

Many Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a cycle between the component.ts and objects.service.ts where I subscribed an observable inside the component, which came from the service.

But it is still a nighmare to find those cycles..